# Text Mining in a string using R

Tags: r, text-mining

I recently started using R and a newbie for data analysis.

Is it possible in R to find the **number of repetitions in a single main string** of data when a string of data is used for searching through it?

Example:
Main string:  '**abcdefghikllabcdefgllabcd'**
and search string: '**lla**'

Desired output: '**abcdefghik lla bcdefg lla bcd**'

[I tried using **grep()** function of R, but It is not working in the desired way and only gives the number of repetitions of search string in multiple main strings.]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works too using regex capture groups:

```
gsub("(lla)"," \\1 ","abcdefghikllabcdefgllabcd")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the gsub() method like this:

```
main_string <- 'abcdefghikllabcdefgllabcd'
search_string <- 'lla'

output_string <- gsub(search_string, paste(' ', search_string, ' ', sep = ''), main_string)
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to tokenize the main_string by splitting it on search_string, you will want to do strsplit(main_string, search_string), which will output three strings excluding 'lla'.

Answer (score 0):

Your question says that you might want to just COUNT the number of occurrences of the search tring in the main string. If that is the case, try this one liner:

```
string = "abcdefghikllabcdefgllabcd"
search  = 'lla'

( nchar(string) - nchar( gsub(search, "", string)) ) / nchar(search)
#returns 2

string2 = "llaabcdefghikllabcdefgllabcdlla"
( nchar(string2) - nchar( gsub(search, "", string2)) ) / nchar(search)
#returns 4
```

NOTE: **Unit-test your solution for matches at the beginning and end of the string** (i.e. make sure it works on 'llaabcdefghikllabcdefgllabcdlla'). I have seen several solutions elsewhere that rely on strsplit() to split on 'lla', but these solutions skip the final 'lla' at the end of the word.

Comment: Thank you. Even counting the number of sub strings is the next problem which I want to post in the forum. Your advance reply saved me a lot of time.